# Why is my menu icon displayed very small in the Chrome app?

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, responsive-design, font-size

I created a basic mobile responsive header with a hamburger menu icon.
Problem: In the Chrome app on phone 2, **my icon is shown very small**, meanwhile, on all the other apps and devices it is displayed in its correct size.

It is displayed **correctly** here:

- Desktop: the responsive device emulator in my Chrome devtools.
- Phone 1: in Samsung Internet browser app (v16.2.5.4) and Chrome app (v101.0.4951.41).
- Phone 2: in Samsung Internet browser app (v16.2.5.4).

It is displayed **incorrectly** here:

- Phone 2: Chrome app (v91.0.4472.101). See: [2 side by side screenshots showing the icon difference (phone B on the left, phone A on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt1Rc.jpg)

My JSX:

```
<div className="screen-container">
  <div className="top-row">
    <AiOutlineMenu className="mobile-menu-icon" />
    ...
  </div>
</div>
/*
The final HTML converts <AiOutlineMenu className="mobile-menu-icon" /> to:
<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" class="mobile-menu-icon" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M904 160H120c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v64c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h784c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-64c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8zm0 624H120c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v64c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h784c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-64c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8zm0-312H120c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v64c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h784c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-64c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8z"></path></svg>
*/
```

My SCSS:

```
.screen-container {
  .top-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;

    .mobile-menu-icon {
      display: unset;
      font-size: 2rem;
      margin-right: 1rem;
    }

  }
}
```

I could update the Chrome app on phone 2, but that is not a real solution since I may not assume that the website visitors will have updated their browser too.

Answer (score 0):

rem means root em, maybe root font size is different? it also have less margin-bottom(2rem). Have you tried with pixel?

Comment: When I change it to `font-size: 20px;` the issue remains. The icon is still displayed extremely small.